# How did Shisui awakened his Mangekyo Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

We know that to awaken Mangekyou Sharingan the wielder must witness the death of someone close to them like Itachi with Shisui's death,
Obito and Kakashi with Rin's, and Sasuke with Itachi's.

So whose death did Shisui see?

Comment: IIRC it was his girlfriend.

Comment: Wikia states it was the death of a close rival. Probably wrong though since I can't find anything corroborating that. I However think it was the death of his family when he and Itachi were both kids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [wiki](http://www.naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shisui_Uchiha): "At the end of the Third Shinobi World War Shisui witnessed his best friend die without being able to do anything to save him, consequently awakening the Mangekyo Sharingan"  The reference is "Itachi Shinden: Book of Dark Night" (which I skipped).